# Unload from S3 and remove all unescaped characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, escaping, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to easily remove all unescaped characters when unloading from Redshift to S3 ?

We have data that contains quotations, tabs, newlines, and backslashes which we'd like to remove.

The only solution I can come up with is doing the unload with the `ESCAPE` switch and then removing all backslashes and characters that follow a backslash.

I'm hoping there is a more robust solution than an `unload` followed by a `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can unload an arbitrary query to S3, not only the raw table, so you can use replace function to get rid of unwanted characters, similar to this:

```
select regexp_replace('f"s2fs''d!
 fds    f','[\n\t''"]', ' ')
```

This one replaces newline, tab, single quote and double quote with space.

Comment: p.s. if you copy the code you will have spaces instead of tab in `fds    f` part, so it won't work as you expected. Originally there was a tab and it was replaced by a space.